# Resizing a vector of 2d points to match a resized image?

Tags: c++, opencv, keypoint

I have an opencv application that uses blob detection to find the centers of white circles.

I run the detection, and end up with my image (at 1920 x 1080 resolution), and a `std::vector<KeyPoint>` of my 2d points.

Mapping the points onto the image, I get this:

[image]

What i need to do now is resize my image to 320 x 240, and scale the 2d points to match.

I use this code:

```
cv::Size imgSize(frame.cols, frame.rows); //original frame size
cv::Size resz(320, 240);                  //resized frame size

cv::Size scaleVal(imgSize.width / resz.width, imgSize.height / resz.height); //the scale value
```

//resize the frame

```
cv::resize(frame, frame, cv::Size(resz));
```

//Scale and draw the points:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < keypoints.size(); i++)
    {
        cv::drawMarker(frame, cv::Point(keypoints[i].pt.x / scaleVal.width, keypoints[i].pt.y / scaleVal.height), Scalar(0, 0, 255), cv::MARKER_CROSS);
        
    }
```

However this gives me:

[image]
What am i missing here?

How can i scale a vector of points to match a resized `cv::Mat` image?

Comment: the height ratio should be 1080/240=4.5, but since it's assigned to a cv::Size that contains integers values it's truncated to 4. Use cv::Size2f for scaleVal

Comment: Thank you! This has solved it. However i had to change all three of the `cv::Size` vars to `cv::Size2f`. Thanks again.

Comment: the second issue is integer division (which gets floored). use `(float)imgSize.width / ...` and so on to make sure those values are floats, not integers, *before* dividing